# How to debug capybara not clicking links?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to use `capybara` for web scraping. Namely, making it click the link, which is a `span` actually, but has `onclick` handler attached:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'capybara/dsl'

include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

visit 'http://example.com'
p current_url
sleep 10
first('#some-id').click
sleep 10
p current_url
```

But judging from `current_url` it fails. For now I'm using `poltergeist` driver. When I run this code against the other (test) page with span having `onclick` handler attached, it works. How can I figure out what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did. Installed `selenium-webdriver`. Switched to driver `:selenium`:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

And added `byebug` after clicking the link. And now I see that clicking the link redirects to the other site, but also opens new window. However, `capybara` reports url didn't change.

**UPD** The issue was that clicking the link opened two new windows (in terms of `capybara`, from user point of view only one more window appeared). That's why `capybara` reported the same url. And with Thomas Walpole's help, I was able to get to the new url of initial window:

```
within_window(Capybara.current_session.windows[-2]) { p current_url }
```

See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601349/how-to-debug-capybara-not-clicking-links/41601505?noredirect=1#comment70407978_41601505) for alternative ways of choosing the window.

Comment: Are you waiting a little bit after clicking the link to check the new url so the browser has time for it to occur?  Are you expecting the url of the current window to change, or is the new url opening in the new window?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I wait 10 seconds before and after clicking the link (see updated question), but `current_url` reports the same value. I'd like to know url of the page in the first window (the second window becomes current). That is, url of the initial window changes (and I can't get to it), but also new window appears at another url, and becomes current.

Comment: Huh?  Capybara doesn't shift the window it's communicating with without you telling it to.  Are you saying the new URL opens in a new window and that's where you want to get the url from?

Comment: Yep, second window becomes current (`firefox`). And I want new url of the initial window. Maybe the javascript code running on the site makes new window current, not sure about that.

Comment: If you want the url of the initial window (the one where you clicked) then what you're doing should be correct - If you want the url of the new window that opens then it would be something like  `within_window(window_opened_by { first('#some-id').click })  { p current_url } )`  otherwise I'm confused

Comment: Feel free to try it yourself: `visit('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g1066457-d479258-Reviews-Shinjuku_Gyoen_National_Garden-Shinjuku_Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html'); ...; find('#ABOVE_THE_FOLD .map_and_listing .detail_section.info .contact_info .taLnk').click`

Comment: Got it working -- the original windows URL appears to stay the same and it opens two new windows - you'll need to use within_window to swap over to whichever of the other windows you want the url from

Comment: Well, thanks, that somewhat explains it. Not sure what are windows in terms of `capybara`, though. Anyways, `within_window` triggers `block passed to #window_opened_by opened 2 windows instead of 1 (Capybara::WindowError)`. How do I choose which window I need?

Comment: Since it's opening 2 you can either use `http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#windows-instance_method` and step through each of them with within_window to find the one you want, or if you know something about the window you want (title, regex that would match URL, etc) you could use the lambda version of within_window - `within_window(->{ title == 'Title of the window' }) do puts current_url end`

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help. For now I'll stick with `within_window(Capybara.current_session.windows[-2])`. We'll see if it'll work out.